# Template class member with different return types

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a template matrix class, e.g. (simplified form):

```cpp
template<typename Scalar, typename Accessor = GenericAccessor>
class Matrix {
public:
  Matrix(size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols, const std::vector<Scalar>& elems)
: num_rows_(num_rows), num_cols_(num_cols),
  accessor_(num_rows, num_cols),
  storage_(elems) {}

private:
  size_t num_rows_;
  size_t num_cols_;

  Accessor accessor_;

  std::vector<Scalar> storage_;
}
```

This class have `Transpose` method, which will return a new Matrix with rows and columns swapped and different accessor type.
My current implementation seems not to work, because i try to return a matrix of different specialization:

```cpp
  Matrix Transpose() {
    if (dynamic_cast<TransposeAccessor*>(accessor_)) {
      return Matrix<Scalar, GenericAccessor>(num_cols_, num_rows_, storage_);
    }

    return Matrix<Scalar, TransposeAccessor>(num_cols_, num_rows_, storage_);
  }
```

I know that return type should match class specialization, but how can i implement `Transpose` method properly then?

Comment: You can't dynamic cast a value to a pointer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to return `Matrix<Scalar, TransposeAccessor >` if `Accessor = GenericAcessor` and the other way round.

One way to do that is to create a helper class template, that allows you to get the *opposite* type (you might need to choose a better name) for your accessor by specializing the template:

```
template<typename T>
struct accessor_trait;

template<>
struct accessor_trait<GenericAcessor> {
    using oppsite_type = TransposeAccessor;
};

template<>
struct accessor_trait<TransposeAccessor> {
    using oppsite_type = GenericAcessor;
};
```

And then your `Transpose` function could look like that:

```
  auto Transpose() {
      return Matrix<Scalar, typename accessor_trait<Accessor>::oppsite_type>(num_cols_, num_rows_, storage_);
  }
```

If you need to use that *oppsite* accessor at various places you might want to write it that way:

```
template<typename Scalar, typename Accessor = GenericAcessor>
class Matrix {
public:
  // create a name alias here to be used at other places
  using OppsiteAccessor = Matrix<Scalar, typename acessor_trait<Accessor>::oppsite_type>;

  Matrix(std::size_t num_rows, std::size_t num_cols, const std::vector<Scalar>& elems)
: num_rows_(num_rows), num_cols_(num_cols),
  accessor_(num_rows, num_cols),
  storage_(elems) {}

  Matrix<Scalar, OppsiteAccessor> Transpose() {
      return Matrix<Scalar, OppsiteAccessor>(num_cols_, num_rows_, storage_);
  }

private:
  std::size_t num_rows_;
  std::size_t num_cols_;

  Accessor accessor_;

  std::vector<Scalar> storage_;
};
```

Comment: @xxx_coder_noscope an additional note: You wrote `GenericAcessor` with only one `c` but for all others with `cc`.

Comment: @xxx_coder_noscope updated the answer case you need that _oppsite_ accessor at different places in your matrix or a helper function.

Comment: Hm, I thought of that, but wanted to try something new. And C++11 solution looks even more concrete than C++20. +1 from me. Tpyos in identifiers do haunt us both though :P

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie having concepts does not mean that other stuff from before c++20 becomes obsolete. Your concept solution is nice if it is an alternative when SFINAE would be required otherwise, e.g. if transpose would need to convert the data in a different way depending on if it is `GenericAccessor` or `TransposeAccessor`.

Comment: and trait approach allows expansion when we can attach more of constant parameters and declarations to particular specialization, for what I like it. Afaik, it's what standard library implementations usually do with streams and strings.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `Afaik, it's what standard library implementations usually do with streams and strings.` yes. The std library, and many libraries that are implemented base one the style of the std use that approach. I generally would advise implementing classes close to the techniques (and naming schemata) of the std because that often allows using helper functions of the std and other libraries as well.

Answer (score 2):

'Matrix' refers to current context here, i.e. you declared function to return one type and you're trying to return two different types. I assume they aren't related. You have to perform choice statically, i.e. to have two separate specializations of 'Transpose'. If accessor can be changed dynamically, then you gotta do some type erasure.

This is out of "crazy ideas" which probably should not be followed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

struct GenericAccesstor {};
struct TransposeAccesstor {};

template<typename T>
concept GenericAccess = requires(T a) {
        {a} -> std::convertible_to<GenericAccesstor>;
};

template<typename T>
concept TransposedAcccess = requires(T a) {
        {a} -> std::convertible_to<TransposeAccesstor>;
};

template < typename Scalar, typename Accessor = GenericAccesstor >
struct Matrix {
    using access_type =  Accessor;
    
    template < GenericAccess A = Accessor >
    auto  Transpose()  -> Matrix<Scalar, TransposeAccesstor > 
    {  return  Matrix<Scalar, TransposeAccesstor>(); }
    
    template < TransposedAcccess A = Accessor >
    auto  Transpose()  -> Matrix<Scalar, GenericAccesstor > 
    {  return  Matrix<Scalar, GenericAccesstor>(); } 
    
};
```

We can check how it works:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix<int, GenericAccesstor> m;
    
    auto m2 = m.Transpose();  
    auto m3 = m2.Transpose();
        
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(m)::access_type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(m2)::access_type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(m3)::access_type).name() << std::endl;
}

/** Output:
16GenericAccesstor
18TransposeAccesstor
16GenericAccesstor  */
```

Tbh, I wouldn't have built Matrix that way at all, because it sound like transposed matrix is a separate type from original one, so I am not sure how good or bad that would be in full implementation.

Comment: But i don't know what Scalar type would be, can i do a partial specialization somehow?

Comment: `because it sound like transposed matrix is a separate type from original one` Those are different types. `Matrix<Scalar, GenericAccesstor >` and `Matrix<Scalar, TransposeAccesstor >` are two distinct types that originate from the same template, but they are still different types?

Comment: @t.niese as that seem to be a dynamic matrix (I think), I'd do that matrix itself is always same type but  acting like a view, and adapter for underlying storage which got those properties. But perhaps in some cases OP can be interested in distinguishing how many times modulo 2 a matrix was transposed.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie hmm I think I get your point. In the end, it depends on what the implementation should really do. Personally, I think that transpose should really change how the data is stored in memory (which the implementation does not seem to do so)  and the type should carry the information if it is stored transposed or not (which would help to reduce many headaches when working with transposed types and not transposed ones, at least for my use cases) but that's hard to judge without knowing the actual use-case.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto Transpose() {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TransposeAccessor,decltype(accessor_)>) {
    return Matrix<Scalar, GenericAccessor>(num_cols_, num_rows_, storage_);
  } else {
    return Matrix<Scalar, TransposeAccessor>(num_cols_, num_rows_, storage_);
  }
}
```